# Does Arrays.sort(pointsBySlope, p.SLOPE_ORDER) depend upon what pointsBySlope[] is?

Tags: java, sorting

Point is a class which has two instance variables which are coordinates of a point. (x,y)
Point implements Comparable interface. But in addition to comparing by their coordinates any point (x1,y1) can also be compared to (x2,y2) which their relative slope to another point (x0,y0). Following is the Point class :

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {

// compare points by slope
public final Comparator<Point> SLOPE_ORDER = new Ordering(); 
private final int x;                              // x coordinate
private final int y;                              // y coordinate

// create the point (x, y)
public Point(int x, int y) {
    /* DO NOT MODIFY */
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

private class Ordering implements Comparator<Point>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Point p1, Point p2) {
        if(slopeTo(p1) - slopeTo(p2) < 0) return -1;
        else if(slopeTo(p1) - slopeTo(p2) > 0) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }

}

// slope between this point and that point
public double slopeTo(Point that) {
    /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    if(this.y == that.y && this.x == that.x) return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    else if(this.y == that.y) return 0;
    else if(this.x == that.x) return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    else return ((double)that.y - (double)this.y)/((double)that.x - (double)this.x);
}

// is this point lexicographically smaller than that one?
// comparing y-coordinates and breaking ties by x-coordinates
public int compareTo(Point that) {
    /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    if(this.y < that.y){
        return -1;
    }else if(this.y > that.y){
        return 1;
    }else{
        if(this.x < that.x) return -1;
        else if(this.x > that.x) return 1;
        else return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I wrote a simple Test Class to test whether the sort by slope works.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    In in = new In(args[0]);
    int N = in.readInt();
    Point[] points = new Point[N];
    Point[] pointsBySlope = new Point[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int x = in.readInt();
        int y = in.readInt();
        points[i] = new Point(x, y);
        pointsBySlope[i] = points[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(points);
    Arrays.sort(pointsBySlope);

    Point p = points[2];
    Arrays.sort(pointsBySlope, p.SLOPE_ORDER);

    p = points[3];
    Arrays.sort(pointsBySlope, p.SLOPE_ORDER);
    for(int i=0;i<pointsBySlope.length;i++){
        System.out.println(pointsBySlope[i].toString()+" , ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n"+"=================================");
    Arrays.sort(pointsBySlope);
    Arrays.sort(pointsBySlope, p.SLOPE_ORDER);
    for(int i=0;i<pointsBySlope.length;i++){
        System.out.println(pointsBySlope[i].toString()+" , ");
    }
}

}
```

The output is

```
(19000, 10000) , 
(18000, 10000) , 
(14000, 10000) , 
(21000, 10000) , 
(32000, 10000) , 
(1234, 5678) , 

(19000, 10000) , 
(14000, 10000) , 
(18000, 10000) , 
(21000, 10000) , 
(32000, 10000) , 
(1234, 5678) ,
```

Why is the output in both cases different? How initially sorting pointsBySlope array by natural order and then sorting by SLOPE_ORDER yield different output when it is directly sorted by SLOPE_ORDER ?

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

During both sorts, `p` is `(19000, 10000)`.  Then, each of `(14000, 10000), (18000, 10000), (21000, 10000), (32000, 10000)` have a "slope to `p`" of `0`.  This means that your comparator won't re-order those points; it will just leave them in whatever order they were in before the sort.  For your second output, that happens to be the natural order of the points; for the first output, it is not.